# Show x* = [...] is optimal for a given problem

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a question like this:

Show $$x^* = [1,1,1,1]$$ is optimal for the following problem:
$$ min\ 6x_1 + .... - 10x_4$$
such that
$$ Ax \preccurlyeq b$$

and I am given the matrix A which is 5x4 and vector b length 4 entries. Generally speaking what is the process behind "solving"/showing this? I know this is an inequality form LP, analogous to inequality form SDP per my text.

EDIT
$$g(\lambda) = -b^TA$$ for $$ A^T\lambda + c = 0$$
-inf otherwise

Comment: The number of columns in $A$ should be equal to the dimension of $x$ in order to multiply $A$ and $x$

Comment: There is a procedure called Certificate of optimality using the dual of this problem. If you can find a dual feasible solution whose objective value is equal to the objective value of this problem (primal) at $x^*$, then $x^*$ is optimal for the primal.

Comment: sorry, yes i edit to say A is 5 row by 4 columns

Comment: Also, this should be something solvable by hand on a single sheet of paper..

Comment: It will be. You might need to work out some cases but you should be able to write the full answer in a single sheet

Comment: i have the dual, I will edit it into the question. I do not see anything useful in text on certificate of optimality